# Pascal Program toString not working

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am working on a Pascal program that works with sets without using the built in operations. However my toString function is not working and I cannot figure out why.

This is the main part of the program

```
    unit isetADT; {// do not change this!}

interface

const
    MAX_SIZE = 100; {// if needed, use value 100; arbitrary}

type
    iset = record {// your type definition goes here}
    arrayint:array[1..MAX_SIZE] of integer;
    setsize:integer;
    end;

procedure makeEmpty(var s:iset);
function isEmpty(s:iset):boolean;
function isMember(n:integer; s:iset):boolean;
function equals(s1,s2:iset):boolean;
function card(s:iset):integer; {// cardinality}

procedure add(n:integer; var s:iset); {// does nothing if n is already a member of s}
procedure remove(n:integer; var s:iset); {// does nothing if n is not in s}

procedure union(s1,s2:iset; var res:iset);
procedure intersect(s1,s2:iset; var res:iset);
procedure diff(s1,s2:iset; var res:iset); {// s1 - s2}
function toString(s:iset):ansistring;

implementation

{// your implementation code goes here}
procedure makeEmpty(var s:iset);
begin
    {s:=[]; clears array, unneeded}
    s.setsize:=0;
end;

function isEmpty(s:iset):boolean;
var
        empty:boolean;
begin
    empty:=false;
    if s.setsize=0  then
        empty:=true;
    isEmpty:=empty;
end;

function isMember(n:integer; s:iset):boolean;
var
    count:integer;
begin
    member:=false;
    if s.setsize>0 then
    begin
        for count:=1 to s.setsize do
        begin
            if s.arrayint[count]=n then
            isMember:=true;
        end;
    end;
end;

function equals(s1,s2:iset):boolean;
var
    equal:boolean;
    count:integer;
begin
    equal:=false;
    if s1.setsize<>s2.setsize then
    else
    begin
        for count:=1 to s1.setsize do
        begin
            if isMember(s1.arrayint[count],s2) then
            equal:=true
            else
            equal:=false;
        end;
    end;
    equals:=equal;
end;

function card(s:iset):integer; {// cardinality}
var
    cardinality:integer;
begin
    cardinality:=s.setsize;
end;


procedure add(n:integer; var s:iset);
begin
    if isMember(n,s) then
    {it is already in the set nothing is done}
    else
    begin
        s.setsize:=s.setsize+1; {adds 1 to the size so that the new member can be added}
        s.arrayint[s.setsize]:=n; {puts member in the newly created space}
    end;
end;

procedure remove(n:integer; var s:iset);
var
    newsize:integer;
    count:integer;
    count2:integer;
begin
    {needed to keep size constant when it is being changed in nested loops}
    newsize:=s.setsize;
    if isMember(n,s) then
    begin
        for count:= 1 to newsize do
        begin
            if s.arrayint[count]=n then
            begin
                for count2:=1 to newsize do
                begin
                s.arrayint[count]:=s.arrayint[count+1]; {replaces the removed member}
                end;
            s.setsize:=s.setsize-1;{removes unneeded size}
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;


procedure union(s1,s2:iset; var res:iset);
var
    count:integer;
    count2:integer;
begin
    makeEmpty(res);
    if equals(s1,s2) then
    {they are the same, nothing is done}
    else
    begin
        {takes a member of s2 and puts it res if it is not in s1 since res is the same as s1}
        for count:=1 to s1.setsize do
        begin
            add(s1.arrayint[count],res);
        end;

        for count2:=1 to s2.setsize do
        begin
            add(s2.arrayint[count2],res);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure intersect(s1,s2:iset; var res:iset);
var
    count:integer;
begin
    if equals(s1,s2) then
    res:=s1 {since they are the same only 1 needs to be returned}
    else
    begin
        for count:=1 to s1.setsize do
        begin
            {number is added to res if it is in both s1 AND s2 only}
            if isMember(s1.arrayint[count],s2) then
                add(s1.arrayint[count],res)
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure diff(s1,s2:iset; var res:iset);
var
    member:boolean;
    count:integer;
    count2:integer;
begin
    member:=false;
    if equals(s1,s2) then
    {if they are the same then nothing is returned because there is no difference}
    makeEmpty(res)
    else
    begin
        for count:=1 to s1.setsize do
        begin
            for count2:=1 to s2.setsize do
            begin
                {if number is in s1 and not s2 then it is true and it is added to res}
                if s1.arrayint[count]=s2.arrayint[count2] then
                    member:=true;
            end;
        if member=false then
            add(s1.arrayint[count],res);
        end;
    end;
end;

function toString(s:iset):ansistring; {this is just a string with no size limit}
var
    print:ansistring;
    x:string;
        i: Integer;
        count:integer;
 begin
    print:='';
    for count:=1 to s.setsize do
    begin
        i:=s.arrayint[count];
        str(i,x);
        print:=print+x+',';
    end;
    print:='{'+ print+'}';
    toString:=print;

end;


end. {END OF PROGRAM}
```

and this is the runner for the program

```
program testisetSample;
uses isetADT;
var
s1,s2,s3 : iset;
i : integer;
begin
makeEmpty(s1); makeEmpty(s2);
for i := 1 to 5 do
add(i,s1);
for i := 3 to 8 do
add(i,s2);
intersect(s1,s2,s3);
writeln(toString(s3));
readln;
end.
```

Comment: Not working is a very limited description, isn't it compiling, if it produces abnormal output what is the output you get, and what do you expect ?

Comment: It is compiling. What it should be doing is printing {3,4,5} because that is where the 2 sets intersect but all that I get is just the {}.

Comment: Wow. That's a massive amount of code for a question asking about a single `toString` function. It seems this can be reduced by removing a lot of irrelevant code, which would make it much more useful to future readers here. (Of course, your [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715183/pascal-program-tostring-not-working#comment45721087_28715891) to the answer you accepted indicates that the majority of what you posted is irrelevant anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious mistake:

You are using

```
    print:=print+'x'+',';
```

when you want

```
    print:=print+x+',';
```

Mistakes in `isMember`:

```
member:=false;
```

you are not setting `isMember`, the returned value will be "random". You could remove `member` altogether and always use `isMember?

```
if s.setsize=0 then
```

Should be `> 0`. But it is not needed

Comment: I still get nothing, the only thing that is printed are the {} for the set and nothing more.

Comment: Looked in the other functions... (generally it seems to be badly styled and pointless, since fpc has some set/list functionality. )

Comment: I know that set operations are built in but we are not allowed to use those, and this is my first experience with Pascal so apologies for the poor design. i changed the isMember function, but the output is still wrong.

Comment: The last comma? Otherwise it works here after all those changes (had to install fpc just for that)

Comment: I tried it a second time and it works, I was just making dumb mistakes and not being able to read/type. I'll just edit the formatting so the final comma doesn't get printed. Thanks for the help!